# filter hook 'authenticate' runs twice

Tags: multisite, filters, hooks, username

I am writing a custom function for logging into wordpress multisite. I take the name of the site via blog_id and append it to the username then pass it into 'authenticate' filter hook.

Eg)

```
Username   Site   blog_id    | New_username (exists in DB as the username)
____________________________________________
Carl       ABC    4          | ABC-Carl
Carl       Paint  1          | Paint-Carl
```

Here is the custom plugin I created under username-prefix.php

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'add_prefix_by_blogid', 10, 3);

function add_prefix_by_blogid($user, $username, $password) {
    //exit("it worked");
    if (is_a($user, 'WP_User') || is_wp_error($user)) {
        return $user;
    }

    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
    $blog_prefixes = array(
        1 => 'Paint',
        4 => 'ABC',
        6 => 'Lakeview'
    );

    if (array_key_exists($blog_id, $blog_prefixes)) {
        $prefix = $blog_prefixes[$blog_id];
        $new_username = $prefix ? $prefix . '-' . $username : $username;
        write_log('This is new_username: ' . $new_username);
        global $wpdb;
        $user_id = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE user_login = %s",
                $new_username
            )
        );

        if ($user_id) {
            // Authenticate the user with the modified username and provided password
            write_log('This is user_id: ' . $user_id);
            $authenticated_user = wp_authenticate($new_username, $password);

            if (is_wp_error($authenticated_user)) {
                return $authenticated_user;
            } else {
                return $authenticated_user;
            }
        } else {
            write_log("User ID not found. User ID " . $user_id . " Username " . $new_username . " Password " . $password);
            return new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('<strong>Error</strong>: Invalid username.'));
        }
    }

    write_log("returning user");
    return $user;
}
```

**Behaviour:**

For the Carl logging into ABC, The username is successfully modified from Carl to ABC-Carl. User ID is found and gets returned. However, it runs it again and the logs show ABC-ABC-Carl.

Logs:

```
[17-Aug-2023 07:07:22 UTC] This is new_username: ABC-Carl
[17-Aug-2023 07:07:22 UTC] This is user_id: 2
[17-Aug-2023 07:07:22 UTC] This is new_username: ABC-ABC-Carl
[17-Aug-2023 07:07:22 UTC] User ID not found. User ID  Username ABC-ABC-Carl Password Password123
```

Seems like for some reason the hook fires twice. Any way to fix this? I am fairly new to Wordpress.